# sphinx and autodocstring from VScode with python code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, docstring

I'm collaborating on a project with people that use vscode. We write Python code.
I asked them to generate the docstrings for their functions, and they used the Autodocstring from vscode. Here is a docstring they came up with:

```
"""
Subclass ObjectCAD renderToFile method to render the scad file
in renders_dir

Arguments:
    file_path {str} -- the destination path for the scad file

Returns:
    None
"""
```

It's supposed to be a Google style docstring.

When I generate a html doc with Sphinx, here is whet I get:

[image]

While I should get something like that:

[image]

Am I missing an option in sphinx configuration? Or is the Autodocstring broken?

Answer (score 4):

The syntax you show is not Google-style syntax (see [here](https://sphinxcontrib-napoleon.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example_google.html#example-google) for detailed examples). It should read:

```
"""
Subclass ObjectCAD renderToFile method to render the scad file
in renders_dir

Args:
    file_path (str): the destination path for the scad file

Returns:
    None
"""
```

The [autoDocstring](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=njpwerner.autodocstring) extension for VSCode must be properly configured to generate Google-style docstrings (look for `autoDocstring.docstringFormat`).

Comment: `Args` is an alias for `Arguments`, so that shouldn't be an issue.

However, you have your argument-type in *curly braces* followed by some hyphens (`file_path {str} --`), when (as in the earlier answer) it should be in parentheses ending with a colon (`file_path (str):`).

Answer (score 3):

> Am I missing an option in sphinx configuration?

If you want to use `sphinx` you need to add the code below in the `settings.json`.

```json
{
    "autoDocstring.docstringFormat": "sphinx"
}
```

Go to VS Code menu:

- On Windows/Linux - **File** > **Preferences** > **Settings**
- On macOS - **Code** > **Preferences** > **Settings**

[image]

Or, file is located (by default VS Code) here:

- Windows `%APPDATA%\Code\User\settings.json`
- macOS `$HOME/Library/Application Support/Code/User/settings.json`
- Linux `$HOME/.config/Code/User/settings.json`

Example with [doctring](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=njpwerner.autodocstring):

```py
def func1(arg1, arg2):
    """
    This function take two arguments, sets the first to equal the second, then returns the new first argument. Pointless.
    :param arg1: Some value
    :param arg2: Another value
    :return: arg1
    """
    arg1 = arg2
    return arg1
```